# Arith-eval (common lisp: a gentle introduction)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm studying [Common Lisp: a gentle introduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) and want to solve all the exercise.

Sometimes I have a different solution. It confuses me and I can't easily understand the standard answer of the book.

For example, with `arith-eval`:

My solution is :

```
(defun arith-eval (x)
  (cond
    ((atom x) x)
    (t (eval (cons (cadr x) 
               (cons (car x)
                 (list (arith-eval (caddr x)))))))))
```

The book's solution:

```
(defun arith-eval (exp)
  (cond ((numberp exp) exp)
        (t (funcall (second exp)
             (arith-eval (first exp))
             (arith-eval (third exp))))))
```

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution is a) not correct and b) using the wrong approach.

**Correctness**

Your function supports expressions like `(1 + (2 + 3))`, but not `((1 + 2) + 3)`.

```
CL-USER 6 > (arith-eval '((3 * 5) + 1))

Error: Illegal car 3 in compound form (3 * 5).
```

When you write such a solution, you need to think what possible arithmetic expressions are and whether your code can compute a solution. Additionally it is a good idea to think of useful test cases and run them:

```
CL-USER 14 > (defparameter *test-cases*
               '( ( ((1 + 2) + 3) . 6)
                  ( (1 + 2 + 3)   . 6)
                  ( (1 + (2 + 3)) . 6)))
*TEST-CASES*

CL-USER 15 > (loop for (test . result) in *test-cases*
                   collect (list (ignore-errors (eql (arith-eval test)
                                                     result))
                                 test))
((NIL ((1 + 2) + 3))    ; failed
 (NIL (1 + 2 + 3))      ; failed, but probably not required
 (T   (1 + (2 + 3))))
```

**Approach**

Your code creates a Lisp form and then calls `eval`, and is doing it in a recursive fashion.

**First rule of solving Lisp exercises: Don't use EVAL**

There is a better approach:

- Since the operator symbol in the expression is already a valid Lisp function, one can just call that and provide the correct arguments. We can take advantage of the built-in evaluation and compute the arguments by calling `arith-eval` recursively. That's the solution in the book.

Still there might be a solution where `eval` makes sense:

- Convert the whole expression from infix to prefix once, and then call `eval` (here `eval` can make sense).

Something like `(eval (infix-to-prefix expression))`.

Now one would have to write the function `infix-to-prefix`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Joswig !  I don't how to express my appreciate for your answer.

I just  try understand what is test-case and study hard right now

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with "`eval` and `funcall` are very different beasts".

The `eval` function takes an S-expression and evaluates it in the "null lexical environment" (essentially, only dynamic variables are visible). The `funcall` function takes a function designator (either a function object or a symbol that has a function binding), and 0 or more arguments. As per normal with functions, the arguments are evaluated in the current lexical environment.

In the general case, I'd advise against using `eval` unless you absolutely need to, `funcall` or `apply` is almost always the right tool for this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am so happy.      
But I really want to know how can people get standard answer base on tutorial of this book.  This is no logic for me.

Comment: @programer5566 Never read that book, I think I started with "Lisp" by Winston and Horne (amazon link: http://www.amazon.com/Lisp-3rd-Edition-Patrick-Winston/dp/0201083191) as a tutorial. It may be worth reading the standard, it's surprisingly readable for a standards document.

Comment: Thanks Vatine, Your are so friendly and nice. I will find out this book and I'm so glad to see you.